Damaging of SWDIO and SWDCLK pins when they are used as output/uartRX
We are developing board with LPC54616. All pins are already used, so we have to use also programming pins, SWDIO as output pin and SWDCLK as uart RX (both signals are connected to additional modul of the board - pins of other processor). We are able to program and run firmware on this board, but programming stop working after few firmware updates. MCUXpresso (v11.1.1) show error (copied from console):
MCUXpresso IDE RedlinkMulti Driver v11.1 (Feb 24 2020 13:54:38 - crt_emu_cm_redlink build 11)
Found chip XML file in C:/.../project_name/Debug\LPC54616J512.xml
Reconnected to existing LinkServer process.
Connecting to probe 1 core 0 (using server started externally) reports:
'Ee(42). Could not connect to core.'
Retrying...
Reconnected to existing LinkServer process.
Server OK but no connection to probe 1 core 0 (after 3 attempts) - Ee(42). Could not connect to core.
Failed on connect: Ee(42). Could not connect to core.
No connection to chip's debug port

We have similar version of this board. There are not used programming pins (SWDCLK and SWDIO) as output/UART and it works fine.
This is 3th proccesor, which is damaged by this way and I dont have any clue what can cause damage of processors.
How can I prevent damage of processor?
Thank you for responses.
EDIT:
There is schematic, it shows how those pins are connected. LDOs are supplied from external 5V power supply and addiotional modul (with STM32H7) is directly connected via header connector. Both modules has common GND and during programming phase is not additional module connected.


Please add some schematics to the question. if it's hardware related, we can't help you if  we don't know how things are connected. It may also be software related: you have a contention on one pin. The internal pin driver heats up, and after some cycles, the IC fails.

How can you tell that the MCU is damaged? Does it get hot?

Thank you response, question is updated now. I think it is damaged, because uart RX is also not working (before this issue it was working fine) and data are successfuly sent by second processor. Also when this happend last time, changing of processor solve this issue. Processor is not hot, it has standard temperature. Other peripherals of the procesor works correctly.

@ON95 What is your question? This is a  Q&A site

If it's not clear, I'm sorry. My question is "How can I prevent damage of processor?". It is already updated.

When you are repurposing SWD pins for other funtions you have to keep a few things in mind.

SWD is not 5V tolerant.
Prevent bus-contention, a resistor is typically used to limit current in this scenario.
I say this because the default state for UART is HIGH, and for SWD it's LOW.
If the load on the net is too high it may not work properly work anymore.
If you repurpose the pins in software, you must use connect-under-reset to regain access to the core.


Thank you for response, overvoltage was applied on SWD pins. Overvoltage protection on those pins solved my problem.
